# Powershell 2.0 invoke-command breaks in the script, but works at the breakpoint

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a powershell script, and part of it needs to check the state of a failover cluster on another system. To do that, I run this line of code (which is normally one line, but I've broken it up into multiple lines for legibility here):

```
$result = @(invoke-command 
            -argumentlist ($test.test_arg_1) 
            -computername ($this.name) 
            -scriptblock { 
                  param($cluster) 
                  import-module failoverclusters; 
                  get-clustergroup "$($cluster)" 
             })
```

And then I check the results. Running the script didn't work right, so I put a breakpoint right after it. Here's the odd thing. At the breakpoint, $result was null. But if I cut and paste the exact line into the shell while the script is suspended, using the same variables, it returns the right results.

I tried to recreate it with a simpler script that I could post here, but running the same command from within a small script with locally defined variables (below), and it ran fine. The only possible scope difference I can think of is that in the broken version it's running as a part of an object scriptmethod that I wrote. But all the variables are available from the suspended breakpoint right after this runs.

Anyone have any thoughts about how I can get this to work?

Working version (again, last line formatted for readability):

```
$test="SQL Server (TEST)"
$comp="test-dbc1"
$result = @(invoke-command -computername $comp 
               -argumentlist $test 
               -scriptblock { 
                     param($sys) 
                     import-module failoverclusters
                     get-clustergroup "$($sys)" 
                })
```

FYI, get-host from the system:

```
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : 65fcc12c-4333-49d8-a340-92690d7aeb23
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

EDIT (7/25 11:00EST) - @raf got me thinking a little bit, and I did a bit of testing. I noticed the following error:

```
PSMessageDetails      :
OriginInfo            : test-dbc1
Exception             : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Processing data from remote
                         server failed with the following error message: The client cannot connect to the destination s
                        pecified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
                         requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the dest
                        ination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following
                         command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". Fo
                        r more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
TargetObject          : System.Management.Automation.PSInvokeExpressionSyncJob
CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (System.Manageme...pressionSyncJob:PSInvokeExpressionSyncJob) [], PSRemotingTransportException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        :
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

So it appears that for some reason it can't connect using winRM, even though suspending the script and running the same manually doesn't throw that error. Anyone have any thoughts on why running within the script would affect whether winrm can connect?

Comment: What are `$test.test_arg_1` and `$this.name`? Echo them out before `$result = @(invoke-command...` line to see if they are set correctly.

Comment: Just tested, they are set correctly, and Result is definitely null afterward.

Comment: Use `Enter-Pssession` cmdlet to remote into your target computer, execute your commands one by one and see where the problem is. Try running `get-clustergroup` without any value to see if it returns what you expect.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean about using enter-pssession.

When I put a write-debug right after the command runs, suspend the script, run the exact same line of code manually, it runs fine and returns the results I'm looking for. So there's nothing inherently wrong with the command as written.

Comment: `Enter-Pssession` does exactly the same thing as `invoke-command` except you will be able to execute your code live and maybe work out what's going wrong.

Comment: Well, except that when I execute the code live, it goes just fine. It's only when it's running as part of this script that the problem seems to surface.